# why @+ sign in android , please , explain this

Tags: android

I am not getting what Author wants to explain , so please explain this , "Use @+ on the first occurrence of a given android:id in a layout (XML) file.  It might be in the definition of the view or it might be in a reference - which ever is first.  In the example above, the EditText view is defined before the Button.  So the @+ is used on the android:id attribute in EditText.  However, if the Button was defined first, the @+ would be used on the relative layout positioning in the Button" ,

..

Read more: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Android-Layout-and-ID-Attribute.aspx#ixzz2MHHdt1wv

Comment: read the documentation ?

Answer (score 2):

`@+` means, that if this id doesn't exists yet, it will be created, otherwise already created id will be used. If you look at R.java - ids is some numeric constants.

If you write just `@` - you should be sure, that id already created.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). It explains a lot, take a look at the ID section.

> The at-symbol (@) at the beginning of the string indicates that the
>   XML parser should parse and expand the rest of the ID string and
>   identify it as an ID resource. The plus-symbol (+) means that this is
>   a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources
>   (in the R.java file). There are a number of other ID resources that
>   are offered by the Android framework. When referencing an Android
>   resource ID, you do not need the plus-symbol, but must add the android
>   package namespace, like so:

```
android:id="@android:id/empty"
```